# Split list of date time in time format flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need time in AM and PM from  List listOfDateTime.
ex: 2:30 PM, 5:30 PM

```
listOfDateTime [2022-10-10 14:30:45.000, 2022-10-10 17:30:45.000, 2022-10-10 18:00:45.000, 2022-10-10 18:30:45.000,2022-10-10 19:30:45.000, 2022-10-10 22:00:45.000, 2022-10-12 17:00:55.000, 2022-10-14 17:00:55.000, 2022-10-10 14:00:45.000,];
```

Comment: It's unclear what you have (a `List<DateTime>`? A `List<String>`?) and what you want.  Your question title says something about splitting a list (which implies that you want to end up with multiple lists), but the rest of the question makes it sound like you just want to format times in a 12-hour AM/PM format instead of a 24-hour format. (If so, use [`DateFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) from `package:intl`.) Can you provide an example of what output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list is String you can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package like this:

```
var listOfDateTime = [2022-10-10 14:30:45.000, 2022-10-10 17:30:45.000, 2022-10-10 18:00:45.000, 2022-10-10 18:30:45.000,2022-10-10 19:30:45.000, 2022-10-10 22:00:45.000, 2022-10-12 17:00:55.000, 2022-10-14 17:00:55.000, 2022-10-10 14:00:45.000,];

var result = listOfDateTime.map((e)=> DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a').parse(e)).toList();
```

If your list contains DateTime:

```
var result = listOfDateTime.map((e)=> DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a').parse(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a').format(e))).toList();
```